# Angular ng-bind-html makes template rendering very slow

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to output a list of jobs each having their description in HTML,
but adding the data-ng-bind-html="job.description" directive makes the template rendering very slow - more than 10 seconds.

The jobs are being returned from the server as JSON e.g.

```
foreach ($jobs as $j) {
        $data_arr[] = [
            'ID' => $j->ID,
            'title' => $j->post_title,
            'description' => $j->post_content, // contains HTML
    ...
]}
// ... return json data
```

The controller looks something like this

```
 api.getJobs().success(function (data) {
                $scope.jobs = data;
            });
```

The template setup it is something like this

```
<div data-ng-repeat="job in jobs">
  <div>{{job.title}}</div>
  <div data-ng-bind-html="job.description"></div>
</div>
```

If I comment out the data-ng-bind-html the template renders fast.
I am only rendering 25 jobs and the HTML is just a few strong and li tags not sure why it is so slow.

Update,

It appears that data-ng-bind-html is a slow operation, finally what worked for me is to only render per job html after some action has been taken by the user.
In my case when the bootstrap accordion containing the job is expanded.

```
<div data-ng-if="status.open" data-ng-bind-html="job.description"></div>
```

Comment: What kind of size of `description` are there?

Comment: around 2000 chars for the html content with no images, actually the problems seems to be worse in chrome - tried on a few pcs - firefox  is rendering OK.

Comment: Is the html valid? I have an app used to output 100's of "comments", many are multiple paragraphs and if i set to 100 per page it is lightning fast. Same process you are doing

Comment: Yah it should be valid the post_content HTML is generated by a wordpress  WYSIWYG editor. The HTML is a is made of up p br and strong tags.

Comment: maybe something else running that is slowing things down?

Comment: Not really, but <textarea>{{job.description}}</textarea> performs fast, there is something about the insertion process that is making it slow, even with the per html rendering I did above the slide down animation of the accordion kinda hangs a little :(.

Comment: @ericsicons Try to implement your custom directive with using `element.html(html)`, because ng-bind-html runs many other stuff. Also I'd use bind-once `::` mechanism to decrease $$watchers

Comment: I've noticed the same issue, specially on Windows Phone. This makes loading about 1 to 2 seconds faster in an ng-repeat with 20 items

Comment: @ericsicons did you get any solution why ng-bind-html is rendering slow ? i am also facing similar problem.